# <myapp>.app.dsym file gets deleted when I build my project

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode3.2

I am building my first iPhone app.  I am using XCode 3.2.6.  Everything was ticking along fine when all of a sudden, I get this strange build error.  The message is shown below:

```
GenerateDSYMFile build/Debug-iphonesimulator/buddy.app.dSYM build/Debug-iphonesimulator/buddy.app/buddy

!error: unable to open executable"
```

From what I have managed to figure out, there is a file called `buddy.app.dSYM` that resides in my /build directory.  If I clean my project, then build, it appears and everything is fine.  However, if I build a second time, I get the error.  If I build a third time, the error is gone, 4th time, I get the error again.  And so on.

The error is consistent with the presence (or lack of) my `buddy.app.dSYM` in my build directory.  ie, it is created, deleted, created, etc ...

So it seems like something is deleting the `buddy.app.dSYM` file every other build.

I recently started working with SQLite in my project.  Other than that I can think of no major changes I have made to my project.

Any ideas?

**Update**

I can't put this as an answer because I am new to the system and not allowed.  But .....

A:  I think I figured it out.  I struggle all day and then 5 mins after I post I get the answer.  Figures.  Anyway, it was to do with the SQLite database I had included in my project under the Resources tab.  I had included it, but then deleted the `.sql` file.  I recreated the file, but with a different name.

So I removed the file from my project and reimported the new `.sql` file.  And no problems since.

I have no idea why this created such a funny error.  If anyone knows, please post.